# How to create a button to save the current timeline in flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5

I have a game made by Flash CS5 ActionScript3. I want to create a button in the game where I can save the current timeline of the game. For example, I stopped at frame 5 and save the game. So when I load it, I should instantly return to frame 5. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like a cookie that stor data in your local machine

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myGameCookie");//creat a sharedobject

function saveCurrentFrame(){
    mySharedObject.data.lastframe= this.currentFrame;//save lastFramePosition
    mySharedObject.flush();
}

function getLastFrame():int{
  if(mySharedObject.data.lastframe){
    return mySharedObject.data.lastframe;
    };
}

function clearLastFrame(){
  mySharedObject.clear();
}
```

Comment: You should always add an explanation to your code snippets.  This doesn't make a complete answer.

Comment: Sir @mgraph, I have this error sir during saving. ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on AlienBuddiesMAIN_fla::MainTimeline/saveCurrentFrame(). Expected 0, got 1.   AlienBuddiesMain is the name of my game sir.

Comment: @GenesisJohnDagdag if u use mouseEvent for a function add `saveCurrentFrame(e:MouseEvent)`

Answer (score 0):

You could also save the number of the frame in a settings file, of your application. Subsequently, when you restart the application, you can load that number in the initialization state, and render from that frame onward when the initialization is complete.

Have a great day.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any code sir for that? Thank you so much.

Comment: On second thought, that solution wouldn't work for the writing part, unless you would use AIR. So using a SharedObject could be the answer you're looking for.